# Issue with React Navigation 6.XX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have 3 bottom tabs in my home screen stack. The first tab, which is home, has some buttons on it. On click of each button, a new screen is supposed to be displayed. So far, it hasn't worked. I keep getting this error:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ScreenName"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'ScreenName'?
```

Here's an overview of my Navigators:

```
StackNavigator -> Home Screen (BottomNavigator) -> HomeStackScreen(Stack Navigtor)...others are just screens in the bottom navigator for now
```

In code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StatusBar, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import { NavigationContainer, Theme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

import { navigationRef } from './NavigationService'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const AuthStack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const BottomStack = createBottomTabNavigator()
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator()

import Home from 'app/screens/Home'
import Notifications from 'app/screens/WearNotifications'

import ScanCloth from 'app/screens/ScanCloth'
import MyWardrobe from 'app/screens/MyWardrobe'

const HomeStackScreen = () => {  // problem occurs with the screens in this navigator
 return <HomeStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
  }}
>
<HomeStack.Screen 
  name="Home"
  component={Home}
/>
<HomeStack.Screen 
  name="ScreenName"
  component={ComponentToDisplayOnClick}
/>
    <HomeStack.Screen 
  name="ScreenName"
  component={ComponentToDisplayOnClick}
/> 
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
}

 const LoggedInNavigator = () => (
 <BottomStack.Navigator
   screenOptions={() => ({
      tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#1B1464',
          height: 65,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          paddingBottom: 10,
          paddingTop: 10
      },
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarLabel: () => {return null}
  })}
>
  <BottomStack.Screen 
      name="HomeStack" 
      component={HomeStackScreen} 
      options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
              <View
                  style={styles.bottomNavCircle} 
              >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="home"
                  color={color}
                  size={30}
                />    
              </View>
          )
      }}
  />
  ... other bottom tabs
 </BottomStack.Navigator>
 )

 const App: React.FC = () => {

 return (
   <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} >

    <Stack.Navigator 
       screenOptions={{
         headerShown: false,
       }}
     >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="UnAuthenticated"
          component={AuthNavigator}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={LoggedInNavigator}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
 )
 }

 export default App
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I only want to navigate to a different screen on my home page, which is the first tab of the bottom navigator. Haven't seen any useful articles for this, all are showing stand alone use cases for navigators.

I started with React Native 12 days ago, from a Flutter background. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question by delaying the navigation call method invocation with `()=>` arrow function. It navigates now, however, the bottom navigation bar still persists. Is there a way to hide the bottom bar on navigation? Thanks

Comment: looks like you've already solved the problem that you mentioned on this question. can you please change the description of the question? or ask another question with a new description? I might have a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed that too. RN noob but I love challenges

Comment: No worries, keep trying :). we are here for you.